# How can I find the owner of a dependency that got hoisted to the root of a Yarn workspace?

Tags: yarnpkg, hoisting, yarn-workspaces

In a project with several yarn workspaces if I do

```
yarn list --pattern some-package
```

I get a list with various versions of `some-package`, example:

```
yarn list v1.5.1
├─ project-a@0.0.0
│  └─ some-package@2.0.0
├─ project-z@0.0.0
│  └─ some-package@3.0.0
└─ some-package@1.0.0
```

In that example, is there a way to find what project added the dependency that got hoisted all the way to the root, `some-package@1.0.0`? There is no `package.json` file at the root, so it must have been hoisted from one of the projects.

Maybe hoisting debug logs?

I know I could grep the whole directory, but this is a **very large** code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a breakdown with: `yarn why some-package`